# Cannot define two pointers together in a struct

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

In C++, why does the following struct definition reports "field has incomplete type" error:

```
struct Element {
    Element* prevPtr = nullptr, nextPtr = nullptr;
};
```

while the second definition works fine:

```
struct Element {
    Element* prevPtr = nullptr;
    Element* nextPtr = nullptr;
};
```

It seems the second pointer cannot be defined together with the first pointer (separated by a comma). Why is that?

Comment: `Element* prevPtr = nullptr, nextPtr = nullptr;` defines a pointer followed by an instance. The `*` belongs to the variable not the type. `Element *prevPtr = nullptr, *nextPtr = nullptr;`

Comment: `using Element_ptr = Element*; Element_ptr prevPtr = nullptr, nextPtr = nullptr;`.  However, the general guidance from many seasoned developers is to avoid defining more than one variable in a statement.